# Using JavaScript to scroll through a list of items in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and also to JavaScript. What I've got currently is a simple webpage that displays information about employees that is read from a database. Part of the information regarding an employee are his paychecks. Currently I receive this information in an array from the site controller. What I want to do is to use JavaScript to scroll through each paycheck displaying one at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery (it comes preloaded in default ASP.NET MVC apps) then I'd take a look at the myriad of scrolling plugins available. My personal preference at the moment is the one here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html